# SQL - Check if field value (money) is 99% of the value where customer is equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Please be advised that I would like to write an SQL query that has the following conditions.

Check if there is a debit amount = between (99% and 101%) of credit amount (and vice versa)
where customer is equal and date is today

Lets say that I have the table below:

```
Customer Debit Credit Amount Processing_Date
1001     D            100    01/12/2020
1001           C      100.02 01/12/2020
1002     D            102    01/12/2020
1002           C      102    01/12/2020
1004     D            106    01/12/2020
1004           C      135    01/12/2020
1005     D            111    01/12/2020
1006     D            123    01/12/2020
```

In this case I want only the 1st 4 records to be displayed.

Can someone suggest what the SQL query should look like to obtain such result?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please don't replace `text`, that we can copy and paste, with an image that we *can't*...

Comment: understood :) but when posting it is losing the column indentation

Comment: Because you didn't put it in a code block/fence.

Comment: Could there be more than one debit and/or credit for a customer on one date?

Comment: thank you Larnu appreciate your assistance will keep this in mind thanks.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: one customer can have more then one debit or credit

Comment: @AlanBartoli The point Andrew is making is if there is a 1:1 relationship between debit/credits or if (as is often the case) there is a M:M relationship. IOW, if the 2nd row had a value of 50 and another row had 50.02, would you need to match the combined value (50 + 50.02 = 100.02)? Don't ignore how corrections or adjustments are made in your system if such is possible.

Comment: it would be a M:M relationship...actually the query provided by our friend Venkataraman R is actually working as you mentioned ie combining the Debits or Credits if there are more than two ie if there is two debits of 50 and one credit of 100.01 i want this to be displayed.

Comment: thank you all once again for your help and commitment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below approach to get the ratio and filter out. I have put constant for today. You can accordingly use `GETDATE()`.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(customerid int, debit char(1), credit char(1),
amt money, dateval date)

INSERT INTO @table
values
(1001,'D',null,100   ,'01/12/2020')
,(1001,null,'C',100.02,'01/12/2020')
,(1002,'D',null,102   ,'01/12/2020')
,(1002,null,'C',102   ,'01/12/2020')
,(1004,'D',null,106   ,'01/12/2020')
,(1004,null,'C',135   ,'01/12/2020')
,(1005,'D',null,111   ,'01/12/2020')
,(1006,'D',null,123   ,'01/12/2020');

;With cte_customerId as
(
select customerId
,sum(case when debit is not null then amt end) as debit
,sum(case when credit is not null then amt end) as credit
from @table
WHERE DATEVAL = '01/12/2020'
group by customerid
)
SELECT * FROM @table where customerid in
(
SELECT customerid FROM cte_customerId
where (credit/debit) between 0.99 and 1.01
or (debit/credit) between 0.99 and 1.01
)
```

```
+------------+-------+--------+--------+------------+
| customerid | debit | credit |  amt   |  dateval   |
+------------+-------+--------+--------+------------+
|       1001 | D     | NULL   | 100.00 | 2020-01-12 |
|       1001 | NULL  | C      | 100.02 | 2020-01-12 |
|       1002 | D     | NULL   | 102.00 | 2020-01-12 |
|       1002 | NULL  | C      | 102.00 | 2020-01-12 |
+------------+-------+--------+--------+------------+
```

Comment: i will try it and let you know. thank you for your time

Comment: thank you for the query provided. I just tried it with my data and can confirm that it is working well. I just wanted to see if i can also make one additional thing. in the DATAVAL where clause I will be giving a range (eg. 01/12/2020 to 02/12/2020) therefore if i have a customer that has a debit of 200 on 01/12/2020 and a credit of 201 on 02/12/2020 the query is returning a value. In my case i dont want this returned since the two transactions happened on a different date. Can you suggest something? Thank you once again for your time.

Comment: @AlanBartoli, you have to apply GROUP BY accordingly. `select customerId,dateval
,sum(case when debit is not null then amt end) as debit
,sum(case when credit is not null then amt end) as credit
from @table
--WHERE DATEVAL = '01/12/2020'
group by customerid,dateval`

Comment: Thank you for your reply i tried this however the result was not coming correct. Assuming i have the following data: `customerid debit credit amt dateval
1324 D NULL 516.58 2020-10-14
1324 D NULL 3082.63 2020-10-26
1324 D NULL 256.74 2020-10-30
1324 NULL C 515.97 2020-11-05
1324 D NULL 515.97 2020-11-05` the resultant is including also the ones with the different dates

Comment: @AlanBartoli,. below query will work. i tested with your data. it is working fine. `;With cte_customerId as
(
select customerId,dateval
,sum(case when debit is not null then amt end) as debit
,sum(case when credit is not null then amt end) as credit
from @table
group by customerid,dateval
),cte_customerDates as
(
SELECT customerid,dateval FROM cte_customerId
where (credit/debit) between 0.99 and 1.01
or (debit/credit) between 0.99 and 1.01
)
SELECT * FROM @table as t
inner join cte_customerDates  as c
on t.customerid = c.customerid
and t.dateval = c.dateval`

Comment: thank you for your support with my request. Just wanted to let you know that the query is working perfectly as expected. Thank you once again for your help.